# How to extract edgeweights from a graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I have a graph with weighted edges, and I'd like to obtain the edge weights of the edges in the graph. Is there a nicer way of doing this than getting the `WeightedAdjacencyMatrix` of the graph? A list of weights that's 1-1 with the `EdgeList` of the graph would be great.

Comment: @R.M the EdgeList doc page says "Edges in EdgeList are given in the same order they are entered for Graph"

Comment: @R.M Exactly the same problem exists with **WeightedAdjacencyMatrix[]**. How do you know which vertex is in which rol/col? Well, you know because the help states that "The vertices Subscript[v, i] are assumed to be in the order given by VertexList[g]"

Comment: @belisarius Ha! You can clearly tell I don't work much with graph objects ;) I'm removing my comment

Comment: @R.M Neither do I. But I was bitten a few times by these doubts :)

Comment: I have spent far too much time trying to understand the role played by a vertex's list position as opposed to the vertex's "name." If one's vertex "names" are consecutive integers, everything works pretty much as expected. The difficulty starts for me when I use MorphologicalGraph, which returns a graph having non-consecutive integer "names" assigned to the vertices. In fact, for MorphologicalGraph, the vertex names constitute a permutation of Range[n]. Hey, what's so confusing about that? Cheer up -- there are only (n! - 1) ways you can be wrong. Hint: use VertexIndex to get back to reality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can still use `WeightedAdjacencyMatrix` and massage the output to a nicer form —

```
g = Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 1}, EdgeWeight -> {2, 3, 4}];
Replace[Most@ArrayRules@UpperTriangularize@WeightedAdjacencyMatrix[g], 
    {x_, y_} :> UndirectedEdge[x, y], {2}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Using `PropertyValue[g,property]` and `Thread` or `Map`:

```
    g = Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 1}, EdgeWeight -> {2, 3, 4}];
    Thread[EdgeList[g] -> PropertyValue[g, EdgeWeight]] 
    Map[# -> PropertyValue[{g, #}, EdgeWeight] &, EdgeList[g]]
```

both give:

[image]

Similarly, use

```
   Thread[{EdgeList[g], PropertyValue[g, EdgeWeight]}] 
   Map[{#, PropertyValue[{g, #}, EdgeWeight]} &, EdgeList[g]]
```

to get a list:

[image]

Comment: The best solution. Using the weighted adjacency matrix does not allow to easily associative edges with weights if graph vertexes are not integers.

Answer (score 5):

```
g = Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 1}, EdgeWeight -> {2, 3, 4}];
AbsoluteOptions[g, EdgeWeight] /. HoldPattern[EdgeWeight -> x_] -> x
```

Comment: +1 How does `HoldPattern` work here?  Any reason for not using `AbsoluteOptions[g, EdgeWeight][[1, 2]]` or `/. (EdgeWeight -> x_) :> x` ?

Comment: @David Nahhh just an old vice